# Toggle Button for Contrast

Tags: jquery, toggle, togglebutton

I've done some searching here, and haven't quite been able to figure this one out. Basically I'm trying to get an image to load a high contrast version of my CSS when I click it, and then reload the page when I click it again. The page reload will restore the contrast.

```
function appendStyleSheet() {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gallanthearts.org/wp-content/themes/Gallant_Hearts/css/high-contrast.css" type="text/css" id="hc_stylesheet" />');
}


$('#contrastbtn').toggle(
  $("#contrastbtn").click(function() {  
        appendStyleSheet(); 
}),
   $("#contrastbtn").click(function() {
    location.reload();
  })
);
```

Comment: you havent actually asked anything, fyi you are using toggle wrong, http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: FYI, toggle() used that way has been deprecated and removed.

Comment: My basic question is how do I create a button that when I click it loads the appendStyleSheet() function, and then when I click it again reloads the page so the stylesheet is removed and the high contrast goes away.